# Diferença entre PATH_SEPARATOR e DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR

Tags: php, constantes, path-separator

A documentação sobre isto é bastante vaga, o pouco que existe não esclarece de forma clara a diferença entre a utilização e finalidade das duas seguintes constantes de PHP:

```
PATH_SEPARATOR
```

e

```
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
```

Á primeira vista, parece que ambas nos dão a mesma aplicação prática, ou seja, detectar o separador dos caminhos no sistema operativo, por exemplo a `/` ou `\`.

Mas o facto de existirem as duas constantes diz-me logo que isto não será verdade, não teriam sido criadas duas coisas para o mesmo exacto efeito!

Lendo o que está presente no manual em [PHP: Constantes pré-definidas - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/dir.constants.php), vejo:

> ## Constantes pré-definidas
>
> As contantes abaixo são definidas por esta extensão e somente estarão
>   disponíveis quando a extensão foi compilada com o PHP ou carregada
>   dinamicamente durante a execução.
>
> DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR (string)
>
> PATH_SEPARATOR (string)

Ou seja, não vejo nada, nem uma pequena descrição da constante está presente.

Se for ver em [PHP: Predefined Constants - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>, fala em `;` e `,` *!?*

## Pergunta

Qual a diferença entre as duas constantes e respectivo uso prático para cada um?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## PATH_SEPARATOR

É um caractere usado para separar diretórios, em uma única string, como se pode ver em [`include_path`](http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) no ficheiro `php.ini`.

- UNIX

  O valor é `:`

  > /var/www/a:/var/www/b
- Windows

  O valor é `;`

  > c:\diretorio\a;c:\diretorio\b

## DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR

Neste caso, está relacionado ao separador `/` no UNIX e `\` no Windows.

**Obs.:** o Windows também aceita o `/` em alguns casos.

Comment: Na shell linux digite `echo $PATH` no caso do Windows digite `echo %path%` - verá a diferença

Answer (score 11):

`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` é o separador utilizado para percorrer diretórios. A gente está acostumado com o `\` no Windows ou o `/` nos *nix.

Já o `PATH_SEPARATOR` é o separador utilizado para agrupar mais diretórios nas variáveis de ambiente (geralmente só na `PATH`). No windows a gente tem o `;` e nos *nixes tem o `:`.

Answer (score 3):

`PATH_SEPARATOR` Essa constante serve para separar caminhos com o caracter correto de acordo com o sistema operacional que no windows são separados por `;`e no linux por `:`

`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, Serve para colocar o caracter separador de diretorio que no windows é `\` e no linux `/`

As duas constantes evitam especificar diretorios/caminhos diretamente (hardcode), o que torna o código portavel.