# Devo usar DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ou a BARRA (/)?

Tags: php, sistema-operacional, diretório

Eu costumo mexer no código-fonte de frameworks, como no caso do **Laravel** para ver como são feitas as estruturas.
Reparei uma coisa interessante no [Laravel 4](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2) em relação ao [Laravel 3](http://laravel3.veliovgroup.com/docs/install).

No [Laravel 3](http://laravel3.veliovgroup.com/docs/install), utiliza-se, para montar caminhos de diretórios, a constante `DS`, que é uma constante declarada com o valor de `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

Exemplo:

```
path('public') . DS . 'index.php';
```

Já no [Laravel 4](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2), vejo códigos como o seguinte:

```
app_storage() . '/views';
```

Eu sei que essa constante `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` é responsável por retornar o caractere separador de diretórios de acordo com o sistema operacional que se está usando.

Eu tinha isso como importante, mas o [Laravel 4](http://laravel3.veliovgroup.com/docs/install) (que é um framework mais atual e mais "por dentro" das novidades do php) simplesmente não usa `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

Alguém sabe se isso tem a ver com as versões antigas do PHP? Digo, em alguma versão eu deveria me importar com `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` e, depois, a partir de determinada versão, isso deixou de ser importante?

Existe realmente alguma diferença na forma com que os sistemas operacionais lêem os separadores de diretórios (exemplo: Ubuntu, Linux, MAC)?

Gostaria de saber isso, pois quero saber se simplemsmente posso fazer isso direto

Exemplo:

```
include_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

ou teria que fazer coisas para evitar riscos de conflitos em sistemas operacionais, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
function my_path($path)
{
    return str_replace(['\\', '//'], DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
}



 include_once __DIR__ . my_path('/vendor/autoload.php');
```

Comment: Esta pergunta pode contribuir em esclarecer sua dúvida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2304/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-path-separator-e-directory-separator

Comment: @Delfino, na verdade não pode ajudar. `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` é usado para separar as pastas `/etc/apache2`. O `PATH_SEPARATOR` é outra coisa. É uma espécie de separador de paths para as variáveis de ambiente do windows, por exemplo. `c:\python;c:\ruby`

Comment: Correto Wallace, porém veja toda a publicação, ela também fala do `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. Me parece que você já tem a resposta. :)

Comment: @Delfino, eu vi lá que eles explicam o que é `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. Mas creio que seja importante também se eu posso simplesmente usar diretamente a `/`, ou se ainda devo usar somente `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu acho o uso da constante pouco elegante, atrapalha na leitura do diretório, porém com o uso de uma nova constante como `DS` eu acho válido, pois minimiza o impacto na aplicação, porém isso somente é relevante se seu sistema pode vir a ser compatível com múltiplas plataformas.

**Mas o mais importante é que o PHP automaticamente converte a `/` quando necessário, conforme a plataforma em execução, portanto use sem moderação.**

Não sei informar qual versão isso passou a valer, mas todas as mais atuais são compatíveis, segue três links (em inglês) que confirmam:

1. https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php#73954
2. http://alanhogan.com/tips/php/directory-separator-not-necessary
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7032949/2766598