# Como definir o path para acessar arquivos no sistema procedural

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como usar o `path` num sistema procedural, a forma correta de definir o/os caminhos, e de acessar os arquivos, e o que mais for importante saber a respeito. Pesquisando encontrei mais exemplos em OOP, e não encontrei nada por aqui sobre este assunto.

Estou usando `../`, e às vezes `../../../../` rsrs então acho que já é hora de arrumar isso.

Sei que posso usar `define`, mas fiquei na dúvida de onde incluir, e não entendi bem o funcionamento dos `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, e as opções. [Nesta pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862826/best-way-to-define-path-in-php), tem vários caminhos definidos, não apenas a raiz, e  quero saber, usando o sistema procedural, como faço pra usar isso. Crio um arquivo com todas estas regras pra cada diretório? Como acesso estes diretórios depois?

Vou postar um exemplo de utilização do `path` para gerar um log de erro (que foi usado [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90026/23400)) e se alguém se dispuser a explicar os detalhes, acho que seria interessante para ilustrar o funcionamento.

```
ini_set('error_log', BASE_DIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'logs' . DS . 'php' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'PHP_errors-' . date('Ym') . '.log');
```

Comment: Qual versão do php está usando? tem algumas coisas que simplificam

Comment: versão 5.5.4 @rray

Comment: Minha sugestão é parecida com a do SOen, definir um arquivo com somente constantes, a primeira delas a raiz(`ROOT_PATH`) do projeto, se precisar pode criar outras como, `TEMPLATE_PATH`, `LIB_PATH` etc.

Comment: [Diferença entre PATH_SEPARATOR e DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2304/91)

Comment: E aí depois como eu chamo nos arquivos do projeto? Faço um `include` em cada arquivo que for usar o caminho? Ou posso colocar o `include` só no arquivo de conexão por exemplo? Não rola uma resposta? :-) Valeu.

Comment: Cada arquivo, que vc utilizar vai precisar do include. Ai chama as constantes direto. `include 'LIB_PATH/funcoes/data.php';`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geralmente crio um arquivo `define.php`, com os diretórios, utilizando as definições anteriores, muito parecido com o exemplo do SO, sempre finalizando a definição com barra.

```
<?php
define('ROOT_DIR', filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT') . '/');
  define('TEMPLATE_DIR', ROOT_DIR . 'class/');
  define('CLASS_DIR', ROOT_DIR . 'class/');
  define('LIB_DIR', ROOT_DIR . 'library/');
  // insira outros diretórios de interesse
```

No código você pode utilizar concatenando sem utilizar barra no começo.

```
<?php
include TEMPLATE_DIR . 'template.html';
include LIB_DIR . 'foo/foo.php';
```

---

No código de exemplo é utilizada uma constante `DS` que é comumente utilizada em substituição à `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. Muitos projetos definem após verificar se não existe, por ser uma prática difundida é necessário fazer essa verificação para não gerar erros.

```
<?php
if (!defined('DS')) {
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}
```

Entretanto não é necessário utilizar essas constantes.

> No Windows tanto a barra (/) quanto a barra invertida (\) são usadas como caracter de separacao do caminho. Em outros ambientes, somente a barra (/).

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.basename.php

Dessa maneira o código poderia ser escrito.

```
<?php
ini_set('error_log', BASE_DIR . '/logs/php/PHP_errors-' . date('Ym') . '.log');
```