# Como pegar o nome do arquivo atual

Tags: php, arquivo

Recentemente tive um problema  na identificação da página atual.

Estava utilizando `__FILE__` para pegar o arquivo atual, e utilizava `substr()` para pegar a string após a ultima ocorrência
de barras, acontece que em alguns sistemas operacionais essas barras funcionam de forma diferente e acabam não retornando o nome da forma esperada.

Existe alguma função/variável que já retorne o nome do arquivo ?

#### O que eu uso atualmente:

```
 echo substr(__FILE__, strrpos(__FILE__, '\\') + 1, -4);
```

#### Antes utilizava:

```
 echo substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/') + 1, -4);
```

#### Aprendi agora:

```
 echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php');
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Creio que o mais simples é isso:

```
<?php
   basename( __FILE__ );
?>
```

Alternativa, que dá até mais informações:

```
<?php
   $path_parts = pathinfo( __FILE__ );
   echo $path_parts['basename'];
?>
```

Veja ambas funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/3zTV1f)**.

Comment: +1 esse pathinfo() é show!

Answer (score 3):

Apenas uma obervação:
Existem duas formas de pegar o nome do arquivo.

Ex.:
Arquivo A.php

```
<?php
   $dir1 = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
   $dir2 = basename( __FILE__ );
        echo "<br><br>Dir 1: ".$dir1;
        echo "<br><br>Dir 2: ".$dir2;
?>
```

Arquivo B.php

```
<? php inlude('A.php'); ?>
```

Ao "compilar" o arquivo B.php, o resultado final será:
Dir 1: B.php
Dir 2: A.php 
Conclusão: Um imprime o local do arquivo que está sendo importado e o outro imprime o arquivo que está sendo executado.

;)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a constante DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR para detectar corretamente qual a barra é utilizada pelo seu sistema operacional para separação de diretórios.

A título de curiosidade, existem outras constantes, como PATH_SEPARATOR (que armazena o carácter responsável por por separar os diretórios do path - no windows é ';' e no linux ':') e PHP_EOL, que armazena o quebra de linha do seu sistema operacional.

O código abaixo é multi-plataforma:

```php
<?php
$file =  substr(strrchr(__FILE__, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR), 1);
echo $file;
```

Referência: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/dir.constants.php

Comment: substr(strrchr(__FILE__, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR),1,-4); resolveria o problema, poderia dizer se DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  é  "compativel" com diferentes S.O pela utilização das barras?

Comment: Esta resposta pode te ajudar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2304/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-path-separator-e-directory-separator

Comment: Sim, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR é uma constante que armazena a "barra" correta do sistema operacional. Apenas para conhecimento, também existe a PATH_SEPARATOR (separador para system paths diferentes so's) e a PHP_EOL (armazena a quebra de linha do teu SO). [http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/dir.constants.php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/dir.constants.php)

Comment: Seria interessante você editar sua pergunta colocando estas informações.

Comment: Alteração feita. Já pode marcar como correta :p

Comment: Oi Willian, sugiro uma lida [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1425/devemos-pedir-para-aceitar-resposta).

Answer (score 1):

A combinação `explode()` & `end()` pode obter o mesmo resultado(pegar o nome do arquivo) atual;

O `explode()` transforma a string retornada por `__FILE__` em um array, o delimitar é a barra de diretórios que pode ser `\` ou `/` e `end()` retorna o último elemento do array que é o nome do arquivo.

```
<?php
  $arquivo = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, __FILE__);
  echo end($arquivo);
```

Comment: Utilizar arrays ao invés da manipulação de texto, nesta situação, seria mais rápido?

Comment: @WilliamOkano, não sei dizer, pode testar no https://3v4l.org/ não tenho acesso agora para verificar o performace.

Comment: @WilliamOkano a sua é alguns milisegundos mais rápida que a solução do rray, porém a solução "basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'.php')" é 20% mais rápida que a sua;

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues, posta o link :)

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues, só `basename(__FILE__)` não resolve?

Comment: @rray eu quero apenas o nome. com isto vem a extensão também, tanto faz usar ___FILE__ ou PHP_SELF, eu fiz o benchmark  na minha maquina utilizando a função microtime_float que encontrei na documentação: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Answer (score 0):

Transformo a string constante **FILE** em um arranjo utilizando o separador de diretórios ( de acordo com sistema operacional - DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ) como o separador de campo para criar o arranjo.
O ultimo elemento deste array é o nome do arquivo e a sua extensão.

Exemplos:

```
<?php

    $foo = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, __FILE__);

    // o ultimo elemento deste array é o nome do arquivo
    $arquivo = end($foo);
?>
```

O mesmo raciocínio pode ser usado para obter a extensão do arquivo

```
<?php

    $foo = explode('.', __FILE__);

    // o último elemento do arranjo
    $extensao = end($foo);
?>
```

Extra: obtendo o caminho único (path) para o arquivo

```
<?php

    // caminho para o arquivo
    $caminho = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
?>
```