# Criação de diretorio com mkdir php

Tags: php

Escrevi uma função em `php` para fazer o upload de arquivos, rodando `localhost` ela funciona normal criando o diretório correto, porem no servidor ele cria errado, se passo o caminho: `home\banners`, ela cria uma pasta com o nome **bootstrap..\assets** e não salva o arquivo, é como se a função não estivesse fazendo uso do terceiro parâmetro do `mkdir(path, mode, recursive = true)`, segue a função:

```
// arquivo config.php
define('DP', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('UPLOAD_DIRECTORY', __DIR__ . '\..\assets' . DP);

// arquivo controllers.php
public function saveUploadFile(string $uploaddirectory = '', UploadedFile $file)
{
    // PEGA EXTENÇÃO DO ARQUIVO
    $_['ext'] = pathinfo($file->getClientFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // RENOMEIA PARA NUMERO EXADECIMAL ALEATORIO
    $_['rename'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
    // JUNTA NOME DO ARQUIVO + EXTENSÇÃO
    $image = sprintf('%s.%0.8s', $_['rename'], $_['ext']);
    // CRIA PATH QUE SERA SALVA A IMAGEM        
    $_['path'] = UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . $uploaddirectory;       
    // SE NÃO EXISTE DIRETORIO CRIAR
    if( !is_dir( $_[ 'path' ] ) ) {
        if( !mkdir( $_['path'], 0777, true ) ){
            exit('falha ao criar arquivo no diretorio '. $_['path']);
        }
    }
    // MOVE ARQUIVO PARA O PATH
    $file->moveTo($_['path'] . DP . $image);
    // DEVOLVE CAMINHO ONDE IMAGEM FOI SALVA
    return $_['path'] . DP . $image;
}
```

Estrutura das pastas:

```
root
  ├── app
  │    └── Controllers
  │            └── Controllers.php
  ├── bootstrap
  │     └── Config.php
  └── assets
       └── // imagens devem ficar aqui
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque:

```
\..\assets
```

Por:

```
/../assets
```

Aliais nem precisa usar:

```
define('DP', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Tanto Windows quanto Linux aceitam `/`, então faça tudo assim:

```
// arquivo config.php
define('UPLOAD_DIRECTORY', __DIR__ . '/../assets/');

// arquivo controllers.php
public function saveUploadFile(string $uploaddirectory = '', UploadedFile $file)
{
    // PEGA EXTENÇÃO DO ARQUIVO
    $_['ext'] = pathinfo($file->getClientFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // RENOMEIA PARA NUMERO EXADECIMAL ALEATORIO
    $_['rename'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
    // JUNTA NOME DO ARQUIVO + EXTENSÇÃO
    $image = sprintf('%s.%0.8s', $_['rename'], $_['ext']);
    // CRIA PATH QUE SERA SALVA A IMAGEM        
    $_['path'] = UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . $uploaddirectory;       
    // SE NÃO EXISTE DIRETORIO CRIAR
    if( !is_dir( $_[ 'path' ] ) ) {
        if( !mkdir( $_['path'], 0777, true ) ){
            exit('falha ao criar arquivo no diretorio '. $_['path']);
        }
    }
    // MOVE ARQUIVO PARA O PATH
    $file->moveTo($_['path'] . '/' . $image);
    // DEVOLVE CAMINHO ONDE IMAGEM FOI SALVA
    return $_['path'] . '/' . $image;
}
```

---

**extras**

Agora sobre o uso de `$_['ext']`, `$_['path']`, etc, realmente não sei porque fazer isto, as variaveis já estão isoladas no escopo de `saveUploadFile`, não tem porque ficar criando um array, outra coisa sua array nem esta iniciada, deveria ter algo assim:

```
public function saveUploadFile(string $uploaddirectory = '', UploadedFile $file)
{
    // PEGA EXTENÇÃO DO ARQUIVO
    $_ = array();
```

Porque se não tiver provavelmente você vai encher o log do PHP com vários **warnings** sem necessidade, ainda sim seria mais pratico só criar as vars diretamente, já que esta no escopo do método, não tem necessidade de arrays.

Outra ciosa que não tem sentido são os parâmetros:

```
saveUploadFile(string $uploaddirectory = '', UploadedFile $file)
```

Não tem porque o primeiro parametro ser opicional, na verdade é impossivel ele ser opicional, ou seja não tem como passar o segundo sem passar o primeiro, o certo seria:

```
saveUploadFile(string $uploaddirectory, UploadedFile $file)
```

O resultado final seria isto:

```
// arquivo config.php
define('UPLOAD_DIRECTORY', __DIR__ . '/../assets/');

// arquivo controllers.php
public function saveUploadFile(string $uploaddirectory, UploadedFile $file)
{
    // PEGA EXTENÇÃO DO ARQUIVO
    $ext = pathinfo($file->getClientFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // RENOMEIA PARA NUMERO EXADECIMAL ALEATORIO
    $rename = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));

    // JUNTA NOME DO ARQUIVO + EXTENSÇÃO
    $image = sprintf('%s.%0.8s', $rename, $ext);

    // CRIA PATH QUE SERA SALVA A IMAGEM        
    $path = UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . $uploaddirectory;

    // SE NÃO EXISTE DIRETORIO CRIAR
    if( !is_dir( $path ) ) {
        if( !mkdir( $path, 0777, true ) ){
            exit('falha ao criar arquivo no diretorio '. $path);
        }
    }

    // MOVE ARQUIVO PARA O PATH
    $file->moveTo($path . '/' . $image);

    // DEVOLVE CAMINHO ONDE IMAGEM FOI SALVA
    return $path . '/' . $image;
}
```

Comment: era isso mesmo, as barras invertidas corrigi outras partes do código também e agora esta criando corretamente, obrigado!

Comment: @HebertLima eu digitei errado uma linha, troque `$_ext = pathinfo($file->getClientFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` por `$ext = pathinfo($file->getClientFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`, já corrigi na resposta

Comment: tinha percebido, e corrigi aqui xD vlw

Comment: Sobre o DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR recomendo ler (já que existe o que chamamos de multiplataforma) https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2304/diferença-entre-path-separator-e-directory-separator

Comment: @MarcosXavier não faz diferença nenhuma para sistemas operacionais dentro de funções nativas do PHP. O unico uso é se você for passar para comandos como `exec()`, se bem que WINDOWS hoje em dia também não sofre mais deste problema, raramente vai usar isto.

Comment: sobre o DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR é costume meu usar, acaba sendo automatico rs

Comment: @HebertLima então não use as coisas no automatico, use quando necessárias :) ... no caso escrever / é escrever bem menos que escrever DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ou DS

Comment: vou rever tambem a parte dos arrays desnecessários e a inicialização, tenho esse habito ruim de não inicializar os arrays =X @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento Questão de boas práticas. São por motivos assim que vão surgindo péssimos códigos. Pequenas coisinhas assim vão deixando o dev relaxado. Meu ponto de vista, não que usar / ou Ds ou DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.

Comment: Caro @MarcosXavier boas praticas é sinônimo de mitos em programação, tem muita coisa que é engano, as pessoas entendem da linguagem mas não entendem da arquitetura do sistema operacional, então inventam fabulas sobre porque deve usar de forma X ou de forma Y. A questão é entender a necessidade de uma feature e o objetivo pelo que foi criado, até mesmo em frameworks grandes eu já encontrei "redundâncias" que você percebe que é por confusão do DEV ou porque simplesmente as pessoas seguem "receitas de bolo", mas não aprendem de fato a essência.

Comment: Discordo da sua opinião  em algumas partes mas respeito. Penso que (falando em TI), receitas de bolo servem exatamente para evitar retrabalhos ou códigos redundantes. Se nesse grande framework qie você citou achou redundância imagina se não tivesse as receitas de bolo. Padrões ajudam evitar (em um projeto com vários devs) que cada um faça do seu jeito,  se você faz sozinho, não vejo problemas em seguir seu próprio padrão. Quanto a não entender arquitetura de sistema nem entrarei no mérito.

Comment: Caro @MarcosXavier o problema é gente seguindo receita de bolo sem aprender o básico e aprender a essência, pra mim você não esta discordando de mim, na verdade você não esta é entendendo a raiz do problema que eu quero falar

Comment: Sempre costumo dizer (tem muitas referências no próprio site, se pesquisar) que a expressão "Boas práticas" geralmente vem acompanhadas de besteira. O tempo anda solidificando essa experiência (já são 30 anos na área, tem coisa que é tiro e queda). As "boas práticas" simplesmente não existem. Se você tem uma razão pra fazer algo, é pela razão (e você diz qual é). Se não diz a razão real, é pq não sabe ao certo. Se tiver algo que você realmente acha "boa prática", não precisa de um nome novo para aquilo. Digo isso para abrir a mente dos colegas que infelizmente vão ouvir muito a frase por aí.

Comment: Na primeira resposta, concordo sobre a essência e sobre discordar e entender, estou entendendo e discordando. Encerro minha parte nessa discussão. Como o Bacco tem muito mais tempo que eu na área e tem opinião formada também e tendo em vista que, o que passar daqui não vai agregar  ao tópico.   Não é nada pessoal, pra mim é uma discussão saudável.